# Custom variable access using 'var' on working on product detail page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, variables

I am trying to access custom product attributes value in product description on product detail page using 'var' Like for e.g {{var waz_origin}}

But i am not getting its value on frontend. See https://prnt.sc/t89rbg
This is how it comes on frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try like this

```
$data_str = " {{var waz_qty_info}}  {{var waz_qty_info}}  {{var waz_qty_info}} ";

$nmeng = array('{{var waz_fabric_width}}', '{{var waz_add_care}}', '{{var waz_qty_info}}');
$nmtur = array('waz_fabric_width_val', 'waz_add_care_val', 'waz_qty_info');

$dt = str_ireplace($nmeng, $nmtur, $data_str);

echo $dt;
```

***I Hope This Helps***